# How to resolve "zsh: permission denied: ansible"?

Tags: macos, ansible, zsh

I'm starting to learn using Ansible, and just finished installing it on my Macbook (MacOS 11.6.2).

I followed the instructions on Ansible's docs as best as I could, and at the end, when it seems the installation was successful and I try to run it, I get this:

```
➜  ~ ansible all -m ping --ask-pass                                                
zsh: permission denied: ansible
```

I tried googling for this error, but most cases deal with running into it when already dealing with remote machines. This is on my local MacOS.

I'm stumped. Can anyone help me figure this out? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I needed to restart my terminal to apply the changes.

D'oh.